# Replace leading dots and slashes from css using php

Tags: php, regex, replace

If I have any of the following paths

```
../../../filename.txt
../../filename.txt
../filename.txt
```

how can i replace any number of '../' with just one '../' e.g.

```
../../../filename.txt
or
../../filename.txt
```

becomes

```
../filename.txt
```

These paths however are situated inside a css string, I do not want to break the string apart to do this, I just want to replace the '../' where they are.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be quite easy with `preg_replace` if you remember to escape the periods:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?:\.\./)+~', '../', $input);
```

This matches one or more consecutive occurrences of `../` and simply writes back `../`.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for the quick correct response. I will select as the answer in a few minutes when it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex

`(\.\./)+`

and replace it with

`../`

---

`+` matches preceding character or group 1 to many times

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to RegEx (mostly for reference, @m.buettner has the best answer).

```
$fn = '../../../filename.txt';
$fn_parts = (array_reverse(explode("../", $fn)));
echo "../" . $fn_parts[0];
```

<sup>[ideone](http://ideone.com/Mvevj5)</sup>

or with ./ if there are none.

```
$fn = 'filename.txt';
$fn_parts = (array_reverse(explode("../", $fn)));
echo (count($fn_parts) > 1 ? "../" : "./") . $fn_parts[0];
```

<sup>[ideone](http://ideone.com/dn1HRj)</sup>